# A user asking questions from an account and answers them from a different account

Tags: discussion

I have seen a situation. A user posted a question, within few minutes (or seconds) that question received a answer with almost similar name as that of OP. Out of curiosity I checked other questions of that asker and I found out that the same answerer who answered this particular question also answered these questions that too are accepted.

So basically, the same user is asking a question and answering from a different account. Or is this pure coincidence that different user answered these questions?

This is [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172263/check-an-item-exists-in-array-jquery/50172310#50172310) in doubt.

My question here is: What should I do in a situation like this?

If required by the community I will also post links to the user accounts of those accounts.

Comment: Flag for moderator attention...? They are the only one who can decide if they're the same user.

Comment: You've earned the ["Eye Of The Tiger"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btPJPFnesV4) badge (Have Tiger's Eye) for "A user asking questions from a account and answers them from different account".

Comment: RIP to the users who also tried to answer the question and were downvoted (probably through this post).

Comment: @JacobH It will be a lesson for them not to answer duplicate questions and questions that does'nt show their effort at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user202729 says in their comment, flag one of the posts for moderator attention. Explain which accounts are involved and ask them to investigate.

It is allowed to answer one's own question; but this should be done from the same account.

It is possible that the user is acting in good faith. But it is also very well possible that the user is trying to create sock puppets to engage in voting fraud.

We can't tell; so flag one of the posts for moderator attention. The moderators can check the history and, if necessary, suspend the accounts involved.

Thank you for **not** posting the accounts; that brings the Meta effect on the user. It's better to let these things be handled discreetly by the moderators.

Comment: I flagged that post for moderator attention.

Comment: He linked to the question. So meta effect working......

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson that assumes the user in question is actually guilty.  The mods can tell if the person is actually guilty, we can only guess.  We really don't need to send meta users on a sock hunt

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think that user  I am the Most Stupid Person meant to correct me. I thanked the asker here for not linking the account, but indirectly it's linked because they posted a link to one of the suspected questions.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I get that part, but I was also refering to the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172263/check-an-item-exists-in-array-jquery/50172310#comment87362751_50172310) he left on the answer.  He pronounced him guilty with only the evidence that us mere mortals have